# Get third party values into JD Edwards?

Tags: iot, jdedwards

I'm doing a small project in IoT .I'm using ARDUINO microcontroller(with temperature sensor)to sense the temperature value.Now i need to get those value into JDE(i.e..into IoT Orchestrator).How do i get those values into JDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Vasanth Kumar, iot integration is very new to everyone as well as oracle has also released some of the android apps recently. Please check some of the apps from oracle jdedwards in play store.

I used to study the oriely's book internet of things. I think programming the iot devices requires the assembly language background knowledge but c the high level language with a visual c++ editor should be included With jde installation as common language between jde and the microcontroller device. BSSV is used for mail transactions and practice BSSV for the message exchange between the microcontroller application amd the JDE, use this mail data to update the required tables. There are n number of devices so it is advised to you to make the protocols and programming by yourself.

Please update me if you have progressed in any particular direction and share with me as we both are in same new boat.